# External PHP scripts to use on multiple pages

Tags: php

I have been searching for a while and cant seem to find what i need. I am trying to use a externa php file somewhat in the same way as .css files are used with the goal of being able to easily change features across the entire website. I have already achieved this by just using fopen() and fgets() on a normal text file with normal html scripts, but i was wondering if this was also possible with the php scripts.  Heres the code i am trying to use:

```
                $open=fopen("site name", "r");

                while(!feof($open)){

                $arr=explode("seperationtext1324",fgets($open));

                echo "<p id='newcomment1'><span class='Uname'>".$arr[0]."</span>".shorten_text($arr[1], 65)."<br/><a class='newcommentlink' href='".$arr[3]."'>".$arr[2]."</a></p>";

                echo "<p id='newcomment2'><span class='Uname'>".$arr[4]."</span>".shorten_text($arr[5], 65)."<br/><a class='newcommentlink' href='".$arr[7]."'>".$arr[6]."</a></p>";

                echo "<p id='newcomment3'><span class='Uname'>".$arr[8]."</span>".shorten_text($arr[9], 65)."<br/><a class='newcommentlink' href='".$arr[11]."'>".$arr[10]."</a></p>";

                echo "<p id='newcomment4'><span class='Uname'>".$arr[12]."</span>".shorten_text($arr[13], 65)."<br/><a class='newcommentlink' href='".$arr[15]."'>".$arr[14]."</a></p>";

                echo "<p id='newcomment5'><span class='Uname'>".$arr[16]."</span>".shorten_text($arr[17], 65)."<br/><a class='newcommentlink' href='".$arr[19]."'>".$arr[18]."</a></p>";}

                fclose($open);

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`include()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: Cool thanks for answering. I didnt know that existed which is a little embarassing.. Thank you again